# LightGBM Regressor miscalibratred/underestimating on high fitted values and overestimating on low fitted values

Tags: machine-learning, regression, predictive-modeling, xgboost, lightgbm

I'm training a pretty standard LightGBM regressor and noticing a strange pattern with the residuals (see images below--I'm bunching the predicted values and taking the observed average for the group). On observations with high fitted values, we consistently underestimate the observed response variable and on observations with low fitted values we consistently overestimate the observed variable. My questions are **why would this pattern emerge** and **what can I do to mitigate it** (beyond applying a post-hoc adjustment). As for the former question, I'm confused why the model wouldn't just take the observations it's already predicting to be particularly high/low and push them to be more extreme.

A little more info below

- I've messed around with a bunch of different hyperparameters and the same patterns seem to appear. The model results below come from a model with `learning_rate=.01, n_estimators=1000, num_leaves=63, subsample=.8, subsample_freq=5, reg_lambda=0`.
- There are a few million observations in the training and test set. The target variable is generally somewhat normally distributed but one in every couple hundred observations is a huge positive outlier (5-10 standard devs above the mean)

[image]

[image]